# How to implement a loop in powershell to split multiple CSV files?

Tags: powershell, loops, csv

I'm looking for a way to add a loop into this piece of code so that it keeps going to a directory and splitting files. There are 40 files that need to be split into smaller chunks. With each loop the file names (of the split files) need to be consecutive, e.g. if one loop creates 3 split files named 1.csv,2.csv,3.csv, then the second loop needs to continue this with 4.csv, and so on.

Many thanks!

```
$sourceCSV = "C:\Users\Mauritz\Desktop\splitter-test\largefiletest1.csv" ;
$startrow = 0 ;
$counter = 1 ;

while ($startrow -lt 1000)
    {

    Import-CSV $sourceCSV | select-object -skip $startrow -first 50 | Export-CSV "C:\Users\Mauritz\Desktop\splitter-test\chunks\$($counter).csv" -NoClobber;

    $startrow += 50 ;
    $counter++ ;

}
```

Comment: Instead of defining one single csv file, use `Get-ChildItem` to iterate over all csv files in a folder. Make sure the output path "C:\Users\Mauritz\Desktop\splitter-test\chunks" exists first

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to divide the number of row(csv) by step and spell them after them

first check if path and file exist

```
$sourceCSV = "C:\Users\Mauritz\Desktop\splitter-test\largefiletest1.csv" ;
$csv = Import-CSV $sourceCSV
$step = 50
$count = ($csv | Measure-Object).Count
0..($count/$step) | foreach {$csv | select-object -skip ($_*$step) -first $step | Export-CSV "C:\Users\Mauritz\Desktop\splitter-test\chunks\$_.csv" }
```

then the second loop

add

```
$counter = 0 ;
```

change name file

```
$_.csv to $($_+$counter).csv
```

and add after loop set the maximum value of the previous loop

```
$counter = $counter + $($count/$step | measure).Count
```

this sample with loop

```
$source = @('.\file1.csv','.\file2.csv')
$step = 6
$counter = 0 ;

$source | ForEach-Object {
    $sourceCSV = $_ ;
    $csv = Import-CSV $sourceCSV
    $count = ($csv | Measure-Object).Count
    $fileCounter = 0..($count/$step)
    $fileCounter | ForEach-Object {$csv | select-object -skip ($_*$step) -first $step | Export-CSV ".\$($_+$counter).csv" }
    $counter = ($fileCounter | Measure-Object).Count
}
```

or use ls Get-ChildItem to get max value file

Comment: How do I implement the 2nd loop with this?

Comment: @MauritzBotha  add #this sample with loop

Comment: @MauritzBotha if I helped you, please (answer as "accepted" / or top)
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just have no way to confirm if the answer is correct or not as it does not work when I run it. Would you be able to post the complete piece of code in one box?

Comment: I don't understand "complete piece of code in one box"

this sample is one box for me